# Two actionbars menus in an activity....one at top and one at bottom

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to implement the menus one at top actionbar and one at bottom like paytm home page. Someone help me how to do it.

Comment: What you have tried and not working?

Comment: I had tried splitactionbar....but in this case all actionbar menus comes down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using Toolbar. The Toolbar class has no ActionBar restrictions, so you can add two instances and add a menu to each of them. You can find a lot of info in the Internet. For example this that tutorial:

http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html